# exponent rules with variables?

Tags: calculus

The problems I am struggling with are $\mathrm{e}^{-20x} \mathrm{e}^x$ and
$\mathrm{e}^{-x} \mathrm{e}^{-7}$
and 
$\left(\mathrm{e}^x\right)^{18}$.

I've tried looking for rules online for how to do these, but I just can't figure them out.

Comment: What do you mean "do"?  Can you elaborate (and maybe punctuate) the question?

Comment: `I've tried looking for rules online` Do you mean like [these](http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/exponents/review/review.html)?

Comment: Imagine that $x$ is fixed real number, and use the usual formulas. That there're variables instead of numbers, it doesn't change anything

Comment: Yes I came across those rules, but they were not helpful for me. I know that e^-20x would be equivalent to e/20x, but I get lost when multiplying the e^x to that

Comment: @pustudent `I know that e^-20x would be equivalent to e/20x` That's both wrong and not useful. Wrong because $\,e^{-20x}= \dfrac{1}{e^{20x}} \ne \dfrac{e}{20x}\,$. Not useful because that's not the rule you need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)\ \ \ e^{-20x}e^x$ This is of the form $a^x\cdot a^x=a^{x+x}$

So, $e^{-20x}e^x=e^{-20x+x}=e^{-19x}$

$2)$ Similarly, $e^{-x}e^{-7}=e^{-x-7}$

$3)$ $(e^x)^{18}=e^{18x}$

This might be [helpful](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/logs/log3/log3.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. that makes more sense to me now